# Passport cannot read property 'password' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I'm currently working on a register and login system with Express, Node, Mongoose and Passport.js and the register mostly works fine (except for that successRedirect doesn't work), but there's a big issue with the login system. For some reason in the method I've created passport cannot read "password" of undefined, so something is coming up as undefined but I can't seem to figure it out. Also, if anyone knows why my successRedirects on the register route aren't working that would be greatly appreciated!

Passport config file:

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("../user");
const passport = require("passport");
const crypto = require("crypto");

//Signup method

module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};

passport.use(
  "local-signup",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    (req, email, password, done) => {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }

          if (user) {
            return done(
              null,
              false,
              req.flash("signupMessage", "That email is already taken.")
            );
          } else {
            let token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString("hex");
            const user = new User();
            user.name = req.body.username;
            user.email = email;
            user.password = user.generateHash(password);
            user.verificationHash = token;
            user.save();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  )
);

// Login method

passport.use(
  "local-login",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    (req, email, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash("loginMessage", "No user found."));
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
          return done(
            null,
            false,
            req.flash("loginMessage", "Oops! Wrong password")
          );
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
```

index.js routes:

```
app
  .route("/register")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render("register", { message: req.flash("signupMessage") });
  })
  .post(
    passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
      successRedirect: "/verify/emailSent",
      failureRedirect: "/register",
      failureFlash: true,
    }),
    (req, res) => {
    }
  );

app
  .route("/login")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render("login", { message: req.flash("loginMessage") });
  })
  .post(
    passport.authenticate("local-login", {
      successRedirect: "/verify/emailSent",
      failureRedirect: "/login",
      failureFlash: true,
    }),
    (req, res) => {
      //if this gets called authentication was succesful.
      //req.user is the authenticated user
    }
  );
```

login file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
  <% } %>
  
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required />
      <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/register">Register</a>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This: `user.password` is the only place you have used `.password`. What does `user` contain there? Did you try putting a `console.log(user);` and see what's in it?

Comment: My bad, totally forgot to share my schema. The `user.password` would come from the Schema stored in a user.js file, which has a password field. So when I create a new `User` and assign it to the variable `user`, I'm passing the password to that schema. My bad for not including that. To answer your question, user would be the pre-made schema in the other file. @Praveen

Comment: Okay, I get it. But what's happening there, when you put `console.log(user);`? are you getting something that you're not expecting?

Comment: @RyanHaraki I have run into the same issue. What was the solution to this issue?